# Google search results shows struts key messages

Tags: jsp, search, struts2, tomcat7, google-search

I have web site hosted on a Tomcat 7.x and using Struts2 as the MVC framework.
When I search my site (in Google or Bing), the results are displaying the message keys instead of the correct text (I attach an image as example)

I guess that the search engines access the compiled .jsp under the "/work" folder where maybe Struts2 hasn't replaced the keys by their correspondent message.

[image]

Has anyone had the same problem? Is it something whith Tomcat configuration or Struts configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Administrating production servers are off-topic on SO. You can only post a question about programming on this site.

Comment: It is not only the google searches. I've opened your site, it shows them too... so you've used getText, but how have you specified those texts ? In which localized properties file ? Give us more details about your problem, like this is unanswerable